# How to develop a Google Apps Script Web App with different stages / different GSuite accounts?

Tags: google-apps-script, clasp

I was wondering how to have different stages (dev. prod) when developing a Google Apps Script webapp. Afaik there is nothing out of the box, especially when you want to have one G Suite Account for dev and another for prod.

The only solution how to handle this, I came up with, is to use [Clasp](https://github.com/google/clasp) and switch between two GSuite Accounts with `clasp logout / login`

My questions are:

- Does this work, or are there any reference to one GSuite Account which break when pushing to another account?
- Is there a better approach?

I think it is better to explain it on an example:

I have a Google App Script project setup with clasp on domain test.mydomain.com with the user user@test.mydomain.com

Now I need to push this with clasp to another project (same name) on a different domain prod.mydomain.com. This project is shared with another user where I have the credentials.

The problem is when I now login with the user in clasp I would need to create a project first right? But the project already exists. So how can I handle that?

Comment: Obviously you just need set up 2 different clasp projects

Comment: zlZimon, could you please clarify why would using a different account for production mean? If the Web App is run under the authority of the owner, it will always run like that, and you can push from any account that has access. Otherwise it will run under the authority of user accessing, and you can still push from any account. If you don't want to exhaust prod. account quotas - you can log in locally. I am honestly curious - could you give some more details on your use case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Does this work?**

Yes, just make sure the account has edit access to be able to push (but I am sure you know that).

**Is there a better approach?**

There sort of is (unless you implicitly meant it), to quote from [issue #42](https://github.com/google/clasp/issues/42) of the clasp project GitHub:

> New flag:
>
> clasp login --local
> Saves .clasprc.json locally, but would use global clasp credentials.
>
> clasp login # global for all projects
> clasp login --creds creds.json # your own creds
> clasp login --local # local project. Useful for multiple Google accounts.
> clasp login --creds creds.json --local # own creds, local

So technically you can use multiple accounts, but in the end, it boils down to your `login` / `logout` technique.

---

Regrading discussion on switching between apps script projects with CLASP, I ended up writing a basic utility script for switching between Apps Script projects to push to (no dependencies, but if you want to manage flags in style, check out the popular [Yargs](https://github.com/yargs/yargs) package):

```
const fs = require('fs').promises;
const { promisify } = require("util");
const { spawn } = require("child_process");

const rl = require("readline");

const promiseAns = () => {
    const dummy = rl.createInterface({
        input: process.stdin
    });

    dummy.question[promisify.custom] = function (query) {
        return new Promise((resolve) => this.question( query, resolve));
    };

    return promisify(dummy.question);
};



/**
 * @summary asks to confirm and exits if ok
 * @param {import("readline").Interface} cons 
 * @param {string} init
 */
const checkExit = async (cons, init) =>{ 

    if ( !/exit/.test(init) ) {
        return;
    }

    const question = promiseAns();

    const ans = await question.bind(cons)(`Are you sure (Y|n)?\n`);

    if (/^Y(?:es)?/i.test(ans)) {
        process.exit();
    }
}

/**
 * @summary repeat question until matches
 * @param {import("readline").Interface} cons 
 * @param {string} query 
 * @param {(ans: string) => boolean} condition 
 * @param {(ans: string) => any} onSuccess 
 */
const askUntil = (cons, query, condition, onSuccess) => cons.question(query, async (ans) => {

    await checkExit(cons, ans);

    if (!condition(ans)) {
        return askUntil(cons, query, condition, onSuccess);
    }

    onSuccess(ans);
});

/**
 * @summary makes readline interface
 */
const makeRL = () => {

    const cons = rl.createInterface({
        input: process.stdin,
        output: process.stdout,
    });

    cons.on("line", (ln) => console.log(ln));

    return cons;
};

process.on("unhandledRejection", (err) => {
    console.log(err);
    process.exit();
});

const APP_CONFIG = {

    paths: {

        dotclasp: "./.clasp.json",

        ids: "./ids.txt"

    }

};

(async (configuration) => {

    const cons = makeRL();

    const { paths: { dotclasp, ids } } = configuration;

    const text = await fs.readFile(ids, { encoding: "utf-8" });

    const lines = text.split(/\r?\n/);

    const relevant = lines.filter((line) => /^(\w+)\s+\w+/.test(line));

    const lookup = {};

    relevant.forEach((lbl) => {
        const [label, id] = lbl.split(/\s+/);
        lookup[label] = id;
    });

    const config = require(dotclasp);

    const [label] = Object.entries(lookup).find(([, id]) => config.scriptId === id);

    cons.emit("line", `Currently selected: ${label}`);

    const { argv } = process;

    const push = argv.includes("--push");

    askUntil(cons, `Select project (${Object.keys(lookup).join(" | ")})\n`, (ans) => lookup[ans], async (ans) => {

        config.scriptId = lookup[ans];

        try {
            await fs.writeFile(dotclasp, JSON.stringify(config), { encoding: "utf-8" });
            cons.emit("line", `switched to ${ans}`);
        }
        catch {
            cons.emit("line", `failed to switch to ${ans}`);
        }

        if (!push) {
            process.exit();
        }

        const cp = spawn(`clasp push --force`, {
            stdio: "inherit",
            shell: true
        });

        cp.on("error", ({ message }) => {
            cons.write(message);
            process.exit();
        });

        cp.on("exit", () => {
            cons.emit("line", `pushed to ${ans}`);
            process.exit();
        });

    });

})(APP_CONFIG);
```

[image: sample run]

Comment: Well when I try this is does not find the scriptId. So in addition to your approach I have to manually change the ScriptId in `.clasp.json`

Comment: Hi @zIZimon - hm, that is only required if you use multiple projects. If this happens on one project with multiple accounts as your question stated my bet would be on a bug in clasp

Comment: Well yes, one GCP project which is in a dev environment and one GCP project which is in the prod environment. How else can you have this?

Comment: @zlZimon - no, two GCPs are ok, I was curious about two google apps script projects - since to get the "could not find the scriptId" you should not share acess between two accounts to the same script project. If they do share - then it seems like a bug

Comment: My bad, my explanation was off. I have one codebase (locally) where I use clasp and 2 GCP projects where one is dev and the other is prod. Afaik one Apps Script Project can only be linked to one GCP project. Therefore I need to one Apps Script Project for each. So when I push to the first one and want to push to the second one I also need to change the scriptId in order to do so, right?

Comment: @zlZimon - ah, thank you for explaining - it makes more sense now! Yes, I think there is (currently) no way around that - if you need to change google apps script projects, then yes, you will have to change scriptIds every time (that's how I do it for one of the clients as well). One can write a small "loader" script that will switch Ids based on what credential is loaded, but I guess it is more trouble than it is worth. You can open a feature request for that, btw, that might be something clasp team will be willing to develop